# Seting up Python on IIS 5.1

Tags: python, iis, cgi, iis-5

I have this test python file

```
import os

print 'Content-type: text/html' 
print 

print '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Python Sample CGI</TITLE></HEAD>'
print '<BODY>'
print "<H1>This is A Sample Python CGI Script</H1>"
print '<br>'
if os.environ.has_key('REMOTE_HOST'):
   print "<p>You have accessed this site from IP: "+os.environ["REMOTE_HOST"]+"</p>"
else:
   print os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']

print '</BODY></html>'
```

I created an application on IIS 5.1 with permission to execute scripts and created a mapping to .py like this:

```
C:\Python30\python.exe -u "%" "%"
```

But when I try to execute the script I got the following error:

```
CGI Error
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are:

C:\Python30\python.exe: can't find '__main__.py' in ''
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\Python30\python.exe -u "%" "%"
```

Close, but it should be "%s". I use:

```
"C:\Python30\python.exe" -u "%s"
```

(The second %s is for command-line <isindex> queries, which will never happen in this century.)

Comment: Thanks...
But now I got other error:

CGI Error
  File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\geoserver\python.py", line 2
    print 'Content-type: text/html' 
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: print is a function under Python 3.0. If you're sure you want to use Python 3.0 for webdev (it's a very rocky area right now; many tools and libraries aren't ready for 3.0), then in CGI you'll need to say “print('Content-type: text/html')” with the parentheses.